# gRPC build is broken after latest Windows update (10.0.19044)

Tags: windows, grpc, conan

With the most recent Windows 10 update (Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.19044 Build 19044) now the gRpc fails to build on Windows 10 for Visual Studio 2022.

```
-- Found: C:/Users/xxx/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.12/_/_/package/871c6303207aa1b539e682559d0b5180e15f0c30/lib/zlib.lib
-- Downloading from https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-bazel-mirror/github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-proto/archive/v0.3.0.tar.gz, if failed, please try configuring again
CMake Error at source_subfolder/cmake/download_archive.cmake:25 (file):
  file DOWNLOAD HASH mismatch

    for file: [C:/.conan/eb2387/1/build_subfolder/http_archives/opencensus-proto-0.3.0/src.tar.gz]
      expected hash: [b7e13f0b4259e80c3070b583c2f39e53153085a6918718b1c710caf7037572b0]
        actual hash: [e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855]
             status: [35;"SSL connect error"]

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  source_subfolder/CMakeLists.txt:355 (download_archive)
```

We tried multiple versions of python/conan/cmake but the problem still occurs no matter what version combination we tried. It also does not matter what revision or version of gRpc we are trying to use it still fails.
If I download the files from both link the actual file hash does match the expected hash (...72b0). The problem also shows up on the public Github Windows runner and now our builds are essentially crippled.

Anybody has any idea what happened and how can we mitigate this?

Comment: Have you tried a docker container for building?

Comment: I have not tried to run the build in a Windows docker container, not sure what difference would it make if using the same Windows version.

Comment: If you calculate the SHA-256 of an empty file, you get the actual hash (`e3b0...855`) shown in your error. The issue appears to be that `https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-bazel-mirror/github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-proto/archive/v0.3.0.tar.gz` doesn't exist (or is empty). I think you should confirm that and then consider posting an issue to that repo.

Comment: I just tried pulling the file and it is 163404 bytes for me and the hash computes correctly (`b7e1...72b0`) so it seems that there's some issue with that Windows version pulling that file. `SSL connect error` is curious.

Comment: The docker container is a micro virtual machine that can run different versions of windows/linux/etc. in order to make sure it compiles always and to eliminate any variations caused by local machine configurations.

Comment: Your error is not related to Conan, but is about your environment. An SSL error occurred so you can't verify the download certificate. Try updating your pip version and then, installing that Conan package again. `pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pip setuptools`

Comment: As mentioned in the post, the Github public windows runner exhibits the same problem so running in a local docker container would not help our build, only if we asked Github to downgrade their windows version.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion of [DazWilkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/609290/dazwilkin) running 'python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' appears to fix the problem. Thanks for the input, the builds seem to be completing now on the public runner also.